# OpenCV SparseMat Compilation Error

Tags: c++, opencv, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use cv::SparseMat. Following is my test program

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    cout<<"Sparse Matrix Test...\n";

    int sizes[] = { 100, 100 };
    cv::SparseMat mySMat(2, sizes, CV_8U );

    mySMat.ref<uchar>(5) = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it as :

```
g++  -o "HelloOpenCV2"  ./src/HelloOpenCV2.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d
```

The compiler throws up the following error:

```
HelloOpenCV2.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5c): undefined reference to `cv::SparseMat::ptr(int, bool, unsigned long*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloOpenCV2] Error 1
```

I can confirm that normal opencv2 programs using cv::Mat work perfectly fine.

Comment: hmm, `mySMat.ref<uchar>(0,5) = 10;` works perfect. you probably need the 2d index.

Comment: Yes, works, thanks loads...!

Comment: wondering how about accessing 1d sparse mat?

Answer (score 0):

```
// 2d , use 2d index:

cout<<"Sparse Matrix Test...\n";

int sizes[] = { 100, 100 };
cv::SparseMat mySMat(2, sizes, CV_8U );

mySMat.ref<uchar>(0,5) = 10;


// 1d, use 1d index:

int sizes1[] = { 100 };
cv::SparseMat mySMat1(1, sizes1, CV_8U );

mySMat1.ref<uchar>(5) = 10;
```